# hortonworks sandbox: connection denied

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

how can I connect to hortonworks' sandbox (2.5) via ssh?

```
ssh maria_dev@127.0.0.1
```

I got the message: `Permission denied, please try again`

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out. It was necessary to put the port at the end.

```
ssh maria_dev@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```